# Checkpoint VPN Linux Client

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, checkpoint

Is there a Linux client for Checkpoint VPN? Preferably for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've heard good things about Shrew, but I've only ever seen it used on Windows.

http://shrew.net/home

Answer (score 16):

I'm using SNX (by checkpoint) and it works perfect.
It can be downloaded from [here](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk41808).

I used [this guide](http://geek-kb.com/?p=134) in order to install snx on my client, check it out and see if you got all the required packages installed.

In addition, you can create a `.snxrc` file in your `/home/user/` directory and include there the server's IP and username like so:

```
server          1.1.1.1
username        itaig
```

Then just run `snx`, you'll be asked to input your password and that's it.

Comment: I just get "SNX: Authentication failed" after I supply the certificate's password. Do I have to authenticate with the Windows client once before it will work, or something?

Comment: @RobinGreen, I've updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: Any idea how SNX would handle 2 factor authentication? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: It's complicated to configure and I haven't done it myself but I know it's doable

Comment: It is no longer supported on linux if ou disable RC4 and 3DES on the firewall :(

Answer (score 6):

The existing client is ancient, and as for now AFAIK, there are no plans to write a newer one.
There are Linux native VPN clients that should work with checkpoint - check out vpnc and raccoon especially.

http://www.vpnc.org/InteropProfiles/checkpoint-profile.pdf  
http://www.fw-1.de/aerasec/ng/vpn-racoon/CP-VPN1-NG-Linux-racoon.html

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully connected to Checkpoint (NGX R75) using Shrew Soft, more info here: https://serverfault.com/a/386021/73387

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your looking for an IPSEC client, but if you are looking for SSL VPN, I have had good luck with the Checkpoint SNX client in Ubuntu.

http://www.checkpoint.com/products/ssl_network_ext/

Comment: Unfortunately this now redirects to their mobile blade site.

Comment: And no longer works with modern ciphers

Answer (score 0):

I also was looking for it AND I've found a checkpoint client VPN on the Checkpoint Users Forums, I'll link it to you tomorrow.

OK Here is the link to the Documentation under RedHat:

http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.checkpoint.com/techsupport/downloads/html/securemote/sr-5-0/SecureClient_NG_build_53328.pdf&ei=48FFS7vqK5Sw4Qacls3_Ag&sa=X&oi=nshc&resnum=1&ct=result&cd=1&ved=0CAwQzgQoAA&usg=AFQjCNGgVXRHVJM7alNik11aQoO_7zYxog

BUT, the Linux client VPN seems to be deprecated and no longer supported, as my own experience, it should be better to use the OpenSwan VPN to connect throught an Checkpoint VPN gateway under linux.

Comment: Link is broken by now as well...

Answer (score 0):

IPSEC pure clients only work if the firewall admin has configured the functionality. In a corporate setting, usually they dont, as Windows and Macs have specific  client software.

From 2021 onwards, SNX on the command line is unfortunately not supported anymore.

You can connect via the mobile web portal upon installing SNX and the Java agent.

Or use my automatic setup script https://github.com/ruyrybeyro/chrootvpn

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450131/vpn-ssl-network-extender-in-firefox/709258 too, for more details.