# Checkpoint VPN on Linux

Tags: linux, vpn, linux-networking, checkpoint

I need to setup a Checkpoint VPN client with a customer who gave me these settings:

- Authentication Type: P12 certificate
- Password: *****
- Peer Site: IP_ADDRESS

They tell me the VPN server is:

- IPSO 6.2
- CheckPoint R70.40

I have nothing more. I can connect with Checkpoint's Windows Client without issues.

What options do I have?

I read other related questions on this and other sites, but there is no definitive answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have connected to Checkpoint NGX (R75) using Shrew Soft VPN Client (in Debian/Ubuntu the package is named "ike").

Start by reading the guide here: http://www.shrew.net/support/wiki/HowtoCheckpoint (since you already have the certificate, you can skip the opening steps about creating one and skip straight to [Converting the Certificate](http://www.shrew.net/support/wiki/HowtoCheckpoint#ConvertingtheCertificate)).

If you have a certificate plus password, it looks like you will be using mutual RSA + XAuth.

I didn't have access to the gateway web configuration interface but I was able to use OpenSSL (try: `openssl pkcs12 --help`) to export the CA and client certificates and private key from my .p12 into three separate files.

Once Shrew is accepting the credentials, you can run `iked -d 6 -F` to see detailed debugging output as the connection is established.

I was still a few settings away from it working at this point, but I found this thread on the Shrew mailing list useful: http://lists.shrew.net/pipermail/vpn-help/2010-May/002413.html (follow the replies). I went through the config files posted by Luca Arzeni, such as in [this message](http://lists.shrew.net/pipermail/vpn-help/2010-May/002418.html), trying each setting, and eventually got past my error ("peer unknown notification") by manually specifying the IKE encryption settings (Phase 1 and Phase 2).

Good luck!